# RESTful API Request

Tags: javascript, html, api

First of all, i'm Brazilian, just to keep you warned for any English mistakes that i can make

I'm trying to send a request throught HTTP for a RESTful API, but i'm not receiving any response

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>BUSAO</title>
    <button type="submit" onclick="get()">GET</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="post()">POST</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function get() {
            const userAction = async() => {
                const response = await fetch('http://scristovao.azurewebsites.net/api/LastPositions', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer <>',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    }
                });
                const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
                // do something with myJson
                console.log(myJson)
            }
        }

        function post() {
            const userAction = async() => {
                const response = await fetch('http://scristovao.azurewebsites.net/api/Login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: {
                        'UserID': '<>',
                        'Password': '<>'
                    }, // string or object
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                });
                const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
                // do something with myJson
                console.log(myJson)
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    <IMG NAME="imgBanner" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%" BORDER="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Those credentials are hopefully not valid!

Comment: @Dumisani Your edit honors you, but it is only of limited use because the values are still visible in the edit history. The only thing that would help is for the OP to change the password immediately.

Comment: @fire-zero Please change your credentials ASAP!

Comment: It's an already expired JWT token, so no security problem here.

Comment: It is not the token we are worried about. It is the credentials passed in the body. See the edit!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your get() and post() will never call the API.

Your function creates a new function which is never called.

```
        function get() {
            const userAction = async() => {} // This creates a new async function, which is not invoked
```

You can even test it yourself!

```
        function get() {
            const userAction = async() => {
                console.log('do get')  // Never gets logged when calling get()
            }
```

So let's remove the function wrapping

```
async function get() {
  console.log('do get')  // Now get logged when calling get()
  const response = await fetch('http://scristovao.azurewebsites.net/api/LastPositions', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  });
  const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
  // do something with myJson
  console.log(myJson)
  return myJson
}
```

Your post function is the same. After removing the wrapping:

```
async function post() {
    const response = await fetch('http://scristovao.azurewebsites.net/api/Login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        'UserID': '<username>',
        'Password': '<password>'
      }, // string or object
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
    // do something with myJson
    console.log(myJson)
  return myJson
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in you snippet, is that you are calling a function on click, which is not returning anything, but only setting a function to a variable. So to get the wanted behaviour you'll should change it to the following:

```js
function get() {
  const userAction = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('http://scristovao.azurewebsites.net/api/LastPositions', ...);
    const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
    // do something with myJson
    console.log(response)
  }
  // call the action itself to start the fetch
  userAction();
  }

function post() {
  const userAction = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('http://scristovao.azurewebsites.net/api/Login', ...);
    const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
    // do something with myJson
    console.log(myJson)
  }
   // call the action itself to start the fetch
   userAction();
  }
```